# Tensorflow, update weights in multiprocessing

Tags: python, tensorflow

I defined a network and each scope contains weights for each process, each process assign its corresponding weights, here is my demo code

```
from multiprocessing import Process

import tensorflow as tf


def init_network(name):
    with tf.name_scope(name):
        x = tf.Variable(int(name))
        return x


def f(name, sess):
    print('step into f()')
    vars = tf.trainable_variables(name)
    print(sess.run(vars[0]))
    sess.run(vars[0].assign(int(name)+10))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    sess = tf.Session()
    x1 = init_network('1')
    x2 = init_network('2')
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    p1 = Process(target=f, args=('1', sess))
    p2 = Process(target=f, args=('2', sess))

    p1.start()
    p2.start()

    p1.join()
    p2.join()
    print(sess.run([x1, x2]))
```

The demo code get stuck and it seems that `sess` can't be shared within different processes, how can I update weights in multiprocessing settings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After googling for a while, I found `multiprocessing` doesn't work with TensorFlow, so, instead, I use `threading`.

```
from threading import Thread

import tensorflow as tf

def init_network(name):
    with tf.name_scope(name):
        x = tf.Variable(int(name))
        return x

def f(name, sess):
    with sess.as_default(), sess.graph.as_default():
        print('step into f()')
        vars = tf.trainable_variables(name)
        print(vars)
        sess.run(vars[0].assign(int(name)+10))
        print(sess.run(vars[0]))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    sess = tf.Session()
    coord = tf.train.Coordinator()

    x1 = init_network('1')
    x2 = init_network('2')
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    print(sess.run([x1, x2]))

    p1 = Thread(target=f, args=('1', sess))
    p2 = Thread(target=f, args=('2', sess))
    p1.start()
    p2.start()
    coord.join([p1, p2])
    print(sess.run([x1, x2]))
```

It works now, the default session is a property of the current thread. If you create a new thread and wish to use the default session in that thread, you must explicitly add a `with sess.as_default():` in that thread's function. And you must explicitly enter a `with sess.graph.as_default():` block to make `sess.graph` the default graph.

`tf.train.Coordinator` is much convenient to join threads. One can also use `thread.join()` method to join threads.